# OWL What's the difference between int and integer type

Tags: semantic-web, owl

I have a data type property which is the number of parking inside the building. that is a data type property. i set the domain to building, but when i tried to set the range of that property, i found that i have two options, which are int and integer.

i couldn't find the difference between then. could you help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OWL uses the XSD datatypes in its specification, so this question has the same answer as [XSD: What is the difference between xs:integer and xs:int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336872/xsd-what-is-the-difference-between-xsinteger-and-xsint), which says:

> "The difference is the following: xs:int is a signed 32-bit integer.  xs:integer is an integer unbounded value."